# React css style file don't want to be imported

Tags: css, reactjs

So I'm working on this project and I have a little issue with importing style.css file

I know the syntax should be like this `import "./style.css"`but when I do that I get this   [Terminal Output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7GD5.png)

Output from `npx browserslist`

```
and_chr 81
and_ff 68
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 12.12
chrome 81
chrome 80
chrome 79
chrome 49
edge 18
firefox 75
firefox 74
ie 11
ios_saf 13.4
ios_saf 13.3
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
ios_saf 12.2-12.4
ios_saf 12.0-12.1
ios_saf 11.3-11.4
ios_saf 9.3
opera 67
safari 13.1
safari 13
safari 12.1
samsung 11.1
samsung 10.1
samsung 4
```

I see the `and_qq but` it's not included in the `package.json` file

this is my files structure : [Image for Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyPuQ.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the message, it states quite clearly that it's a browserlist error, check your browserlist config.

Comment: My Browserlist?

Comment: Look for `.browserslistrc` file, or "browserslist" field in your `package.json` file. The error msg says there exists an invalid value `and_qq`, remove it.

Comment: do you have any css loader or webpack module for it?

Comment: nothing called `and_qq` on the `package.json` and @SefaSönmez no I don't have any

Comment: Try run `npx browserslist` in terminal and post the output.

Comment: Also post the `post-css` loader related options in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: @hackape posted the output

Comment: @RedditUpvote I find a potential solution here: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/382#issuecomment-504656114

Answer (score 0):

I got it simply go to

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

and remove the `"not dead"` and run `npm run build` and it worked for me